# Cannot highlight or add comments to WPS PDF reader

Tags: wps

I am using WPS PDF reader on Ubuntu 22.04, and I cannot see the comments and highlights section. This is how my ribbon looks like

[image]

It only shows "Read" tag

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried the PDFs in the link you indicated, but still I cannot see any options to comment or annotate them